# laravel ::find not found in class

Tags: php, laravel

I have a few articles in the database and I am trying to find a specific one by searching for its title. This is my controller.

```
public function showArticle($title)
{
   $article = Article::find($title);

   return view('article.show', compact('article'));

}
```

This is the error I get in phpStorm: Method "findOrFail" not found in class App/Article.

This is my model:

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



    class Article extends Model
    {
       protected $fillable =
       [
        'title',
        'description',
        'published_at'
       ];
    }
```

This is my view where I am trying to show the title and description of the article.

```
    @extends('layouts.master')

    @section('title', 'All articles')

    @section('content')



    <h1>{{$article->title}}</h1>


    <article>

        {{$article->description}}

    </article>

   @stop
```

When I try to load the view I get the following error:

Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/resources/views/article/show.blade.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find()` method does not work with any attribute you want. You have to pass the id of the article to achieve that. Also finding articles by title instead of id is much much slower.
But if you really want to do it, you can write something like:

```
$article = Article::where('title', $title)->first();
```

Then in your view, do something like:

```
    @extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'All articles')

@section('content')

@if($article)

<h1>{{$article->title}}</h1>


<article>

    {{$article->description}}

</article>

@else
    Article not found
@endif
```

@stop

Check the docs for further reference:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Find article with specific title

```
Article::where('title', '=', $title)
```

Method `find()` is looking for primary key defined in `Model` class (by default is `id` column).

## 2. `compact()` function

View throws an error because you send an array to view, not the object.

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> compact — Create array containing variables and their values

Then in your `Controller` change `compact('article')` to `$article` or change syntax in your blade file to array (`$article['description']`).

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
$article = Article::all()->find($title);
```

Laravel 5.3

Comment: Please give more explanation as to why this is the correct answer so future visitors can understand.

Comment: Very bad practice, get all Articles and then filter the collection?